# Add variable number of days to date

Tags: php

How do I add a variable number of days to a date in PHP? All I've found is examples calculating with a specific number of days, not a variable.

```
$date = $row["date"]; // i.e 2015-12-13
$days = $row["days"]; // i.e 10
```

I want the output (in this example `2015-12-23`) to be put in variable `$futuredate`.

Thanks!

Comment: `$daysToAdd = 5; $date = new DateTime($rows['date']); $interval = new DateInterval('P' . $daysToAdd . 'D')`; $date->add($interval);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do this with `strtotime()` and `date()` functions

```
$date = $row['date'];
$days = $row['days'];
$futuredate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date) + (24*60*60*$days));
```

Comment: And hope that you aren't adding a value that takes you into daylight savings.... but why `*1000`, unix timestamps are measured in seconds, not in milliseconds

Comment: Why not just `$newdate = date("d/m/Y",strtotime('+ ' . $days . ' days',strtotime($date)));`

Comment: Receiving '1990-01-17'. Incorrect server time settings?

Comment: I don't know, I try it and I get the correct value
What is the `$row['date']` exactly value ?

Comment: It works when value of $date is assigned from database but not entered manually in code. But that's fine with me! Thank you!